# HTML5 GEO on Mobile Chrome not working indoor due to google cdn not available in CHINA

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

This issue is really freaky....maybe you know if browser uses html5 geo to locate...it will connect with some CDN for geo stuffs...in Chrome it will try to connect with google CDN if mobile is under wifi or network but GPS not available.

It means Android+Chrome (any version) in CHINA HTML5 geo can only work outdoor...indoor will fail (timeout). Previously I think it can be fixed by changing CDN ...but i fail for chrome never allow to do it.

Maybe there are two ways to resolve this issue.

1. Find a way to let user chrome not connect with google CDN but other available CDN.
2. Prepare necessary geo js et al on server and flag something to inhibit chrome connecting with google CDN.

Actually I do not know if above ways are doable or not....anyone could help ?

BR
Caesar